# How to get slices of Python list to get combination of consecutive elements?

Tags: python, list, sequence

Let's say I have a list

`l = ['p4', 'p6', 'p7', 'p9']`

and I want to get an output like this `[['p4', 'p6'], ['p6', 'p7'], ['p7', 'p9']]` , the order is a must (I don't want a combination of elements).Is there a function in Python that does that?

Comment: Can you add more result data?

Comment: Why do you have ['p4', 'p6'] repeated twice is this intentional?

Comment: `itertools` may solve your problem.  I'm not sure, because your problem statement is not clear.

Comment: @them thank you for pointing that out, it was a typo i have corrected my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get pair of consecutive elements, use `zip`

```
>>> list(zip(l, l[1:]))
[('p4', 'p6'), ('p6', 'p7'), ('p7', 'p9')]
```

To have all the inner elements as lists, use `map`

```
>>> list(map(list, zip(l, l[1:])))
[['p4', 'p6'], ['p6', 'p7'], ['p7', 'p9']]
```

Comment: I need the elements to be in the original order not a combination of all the elements, I have edited my question as it contained a typo.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ['p4', 'p6', 'p7', 'p8', 'p9']
finalList = []

for i in range(0, len(l)-1):
    tempList = [l[i], l[i+1]]
    finalList.append(tempList)

print(finalList)

>> [['p4', 'p6'], ['p6', 'p7'], ['p7', 'p8'], ['p8', 'p9']]
```